# Adding Try/Catch on logging file path before script runs

Tags: powershell, scripting, try-catch

So I've got a big script and I'm needing to add some functionality for killing the script if logging cannot happen. My first idea is to do a try catch on the log file path... So basically if the path to the log file cannot be reached or if the directory specified in the path cannot be written to, then exit gracefully.
I'm sure there's better ways but this is the best one I can come up with. Now implementing that has been a chore, below is a truncated script block (I left out the script blocks for the 7 functions to keep the below a bit shorter).  The code in that section does not work.. it's actually ignored so if I intentionally put a typo in the $logfilepath variable, the script happily runs anyway. Which is the opposite of what it should do.

```
<#
#---------------------------------------------------------[Initializations]-------------------------------------------------------- 
 Param (
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
[Switch]$LogOnly
)

#  Dot Source required Function and config files
#. "\\server\scripts\Logging_Functions.ps1" 
. "c:\users\documents\powershell\Functions\Logging_Functions.ps1"
. "c:\users\documents\powershell\Litmos_Groups\config.txt"

#  Error Action
$ErrorActionPreference = 'silentlycontinue'
#  Debug preference
$global:DebugPreference = "continue"
#  WhatIf Preference, uncomment to run script in a logging only function
#$WhatIfPreference = $true

#----------------------------------------------------------[Declarations]----------------------------------------------------------
  
#  Script Version
$sScriptVersion = "1.0"

Import-Module ActiveDirectory


#----------------------------------------------------------[Functions]-------------------------------------------------------------


Function Get-DirectReport {...}

Function New-ReportToGroup {...}

Function New-ReportToGroup_logonly {...}

Function Get-DReports {...}

Function Set-RTGmembers {...}

Function Set-RTGmembers_logonly {...}

Function Remove-OOSGroups {...}

Function Remove-OOSGroups_logonly {...}

#----------------------------------------------[ Execution ]------------------------------------------------
# Below checks for logpath viability    
if (-not (Test-path -Literalpath $sLogFile)) {
        try {
            " " | set-content -encoding utf8 -literalpath $sLogFile -erroraction Stop
            }
        Catch {
            Write-Eventlog -logname 'Application' -Source 'PS_Scripts' -EntryType Error -EventId 8675 -Message "Set-LitmosGroups5 encountered an error. LogPath not reachable or log file not found"
            -ExitGracefully $True
            Break
        }
    }
    
    Foreach ($Manager in $Managers) {
        if (-not $LogOnly) {
        $Directreports = Get-Directreport $manager -norecurse  | Select-Object -expand samAccountName
        $script:AddUserCount += ($DirectReports | Measure-Object).count
        $time = (Get-Date).ToString('T')
            New-ReportToGroup
            Get-DReports
            Set-RTGmembers
            Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue "Direct reports are: $Directreports"
            Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue "========================[$Time ]==============================="
            
     } else {
            $script:LOAddUserCount += ($DirectReports | Measure-Object).count
            New-ReportToGroup_logonly
            Get-DReports
            Set-RTGmembers_logonly
            Log-Write -LogPath $sLogOnlyFile -LineValue "========================[ LogOnly ]==============================="  
        }
      }
    Foreach ($Report in $ReportsTo) {
        If (-not $LogOnly){
        Remove-OOSGroups
    } else {
        Remove-OOSGroups_logonly
            }
       }
    
    if (-not $LogOnly) {
        Log-Write -Logpath $sLogPath -Linevalue "$AddUserCount Total users matched"
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogPath -Linevalue "$AddGroupCount New groups added"
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogPath -Linevalue "$GroupsRemoved groups removed"
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogPath -Linevalue "====[END]====="
    } else {
        Log-Write -Logpath $sLogOnlyPath -Linevalue "$LOAdduserCount Users who would be added"
        Log-Write -Logpath $sLogOnlyPath -Linevalue "$LOGroupCount Groups that would be added"
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogOnlyPath -Linevalue "$LOGroupsRemoved Groups that would be removed"
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogOnlyPath -Linevalue "====[END]====="
    }
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me.  Are you saying that the code in the `[ Execution ]` section still runs, even if `$LogFile` is not valid (i.e. `Test-path -Literalpath $sLogFile` returns false?

Comment: What is `-ExitGracefully $True` doing in the middle of the `catch` block? Did you mean to write `exit 0` or `return`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I found that block on a random blog where the personw as trying to do something 'similar' to what I'm wanting. I assumed that if the 'catch' was triggered then that would allow the script to Exit gracefully. Then I added the bit about trying to spit something to the Event Log about it.

Comment: @boxdog No so my question only revolves around the try/catch block at the beginning of the Execution section. If $sLogFile is broken, the script still runs when I'd rather it exited.

Comment: You can't expect to catch any errors if your `$ErrorActionPreference` is 'silentlycontinue'.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon you might be partially onto something. Commenting that line out while breaking the logpath value the script still ignore the try/catch.

Comment: I'm not partially onto something, I know what the error is. I encourage you to read this complete article https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-try-catch/

Comment: Let me rephrase.. Yeah you are absolutely right that I was overriding (for lack of better words) the Try/Catch by globally setting the Error Pref. But, even after making the suggested change my try/catch is still ignored when ran. I've read that article before, I will read it again but I saw nothing in there that helped me with my syntax issue.  I did not mean to offend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I won't say that these guys did not help, especially the suggestion to uncomment my ErrorActionpreference by @santiagosquarzon.  But the solution to what I was looking for was encapsulating my foreach loops inside the if/else for the $sLogPath. If/Elses, ForEach... they are get easily twisted up in my head.
So something like this:

```
if (test-path $sLogPath) {
     
    Foreach ($Manager in $Managers) {
        if (-not $LogOnly) {
       $Directreports = Get-Directreport $manager -norecurse  | Select-Object -expand samAccountName
       $script:AddUserCount += ($DirectReports | Measure-Object).count
        $time = (Get-Date).ToString('T')
          New-ReportToGroup
          Get-DReports
          Set-RTGmembers
          Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue "Direct reports are: $Directreports"
          Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue "========================[$Time ]==============================="
        
    } else {
        $script:LOAddUserCount += ($DirectReports | Measure-Object).count
        New-ReportToGroup_logonly
        Get-DReports
        Set-RTGmembers_logonly
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogOnlyFile -LineValue "========================[ LogOnly ]==============================="  
    }
  }

  else {
       Write-Eventlog -logname 'Application' -Source 'PS_Scripts' -EntryType Error -EventId 8675 -Message "Set-LitmosGroups5 encountered an error. LogPath not reachable or log file not found"
       write-host "True"
       Return
    }
Foreach ($Report in $ReportsTo) {
     If (-not $LogOnly){
     Remove-OOSGroups
  } else {
     Remove-OOSGroups_logonly
     }
 }

 if (-not $LogOnly) {
   Log-Write -Logpath $sLogPath -Linevalue "$AddUserCount Total users matched"
   Log-Write -LogPath $sLogPath -Linevalue "$AddGroupCount New groups added"
   Log-Write -LogPath $sLogPath -Linevalue "$GroupsRemoved groups removed"
   Log-Write -LogPath $sLogPath -Linevalue "====[END]====="
} else {
    Log-Write -Logpath $sLogOnlyPath -Linevalue "$LOAdduserCount Users who would be added"
    Log-Write -Logpath $sLogOnlyPath -Linevalue "$LOGroupCount Groups that would be added"
    Log-Write -LogPath $sLogOnlyPath -Linevalue "$LOGroupsRemoved Groups that would be removed"
    Log-Write -LogPath $sLogOnlyPath -Linevalue "====[END]====="
  }

}
```